# interpret string as variable in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have some public const strings in c# console application as shown below:

```
//Account one
    public const string POP_USER1 = "abc@abcd.com";
    public const string POP_PWD1 = "abc";

    //Account two
    public const string POP_USER2 = "xyz@abcd.com";
    public const string POP_PWD2 = "xyz";

    //Account three
    public const string POP_USER3 = "pqr@abcd.com";
    public const string POP_PWD3 = "pqr;
```

We are using c# MailMan to retrieve emails present in those accounts.
I simply wrote a for loop 3 times:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
 {
    eEmails obj = new eEmails (i);
 }
```

In the constructor of eEmails, I am writing the below logic:

```
public eEmails (int counter)
{
   MailMan obj = new MailMan()
   obj.PopUsername =  "POP_USER" + counter;
   obj.PopPassword = "POP_PWD" + counter;
}
```

The lines where I am assigning user name and passwords, I need to fetch the exact const variable (i.e., POP_USER1, POP_USER2, POP_USER3 etc.,)

However I am not able to get the variable dynamically.
I can simply write 3 if blocks in eEmails (int counter), but I didnt like that way.
can somebody advise a better way of handling this situation without using separate if blocks for each user??

Comment: Define the data as Array or List? List<POPUserData> for example?

Comment: Defining your constants as Arrays of String(`String[] POPUSER = new String[] {"User1","User2","User3"};` and the same for passwords) would do the trick. I think it is the simplest solution. Note, however, that defining the passwords unencrypted in the source code is not safe.

Comment: Your current `eEmails` implementation has a bug. You are assigning the password to the username property.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for noticing, thats a type in SO.

Comment: @ThunderGr: don't do like that. Your data structure implies that all usernames belong together and all password belong together. That's not a good idea. Instead a username and a password belongs together and you want a list of that. See Tim's answer.

Comment: @ThomasW: I just provided a suggestion without altering his logic of implementation, rather than provide a suggestion that would fit my logic of implementation. If he had them in a structure, I would suggest something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class instead of `strings`, then your code becomes more redable and maintainable and it'll also be less error-prone. Here is an example using a `List<PopServerAccount>` as container:

```
public class PopServerAccount
{ 
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}

    public override bool  Equals(object obj)
    {
        PopServerAccount p2 = obj as PopServerAccount;
        if (p2 == null) return false;
        return Username == p2.Username;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Username.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Username;
    }
}
```

now change the signature of your method:

```
public eEmails (PopServerAccount pop)
{
    MailMan obj = new MailMan()
    obj.PopUsername =  pop.Username;
    obj.PopPassword = pop.Password;
}
```

Sample data:

```
var myPopServers = new List<PopServerAccount> 
{
    new PopServerAccount{ Username = "abc@abcd.com", Password = "abc"},new PopServerAccount{ Username = "xyz@abcd.com", Password = "xyz"}
};
```

Use a loop and call your method:

```
foreach (PopServerAccount pop in myPopServers)
{ 
    eEmails(pop);
}
```

Comment: not sure whats wrong, in eEmails(pop){} , I am not getting the properties of pop. when I say pop and put dot (.) intelligence not showing anything?

Comment: @mmssaann: i cannot reproduce this issue. Maybe you need to show your code in your question.

Comment: Intelligence is not showing up only in that particular file, however the properties are accessible if I type them explicitly I am not getting any compile error. I think this is more of intelligence issue.

Comment: @mmssaann: are these properties the only which you are missing or are no properties visible? Is this a separate class library, have you recompiled all (also in debug mode)?

Comment: none of the properties are visible I am afraid. All files are in the same application under same name space everything compiles successfully.